# Central Limit Theorem on Exponential population

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$ (i.e., exponential
>   distribution with mean $\beta > 0$) are iid. Let $T_k =
>  \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$, $k = 1, 2, \dots$. Let $\mathcal{N}(\mu,
>  \sigma^2)$ denote a normally-distributed random variable with mean
>   $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Show that there exist sequences of
>   constants $a_n, b_n$ such that $$a_n(T_n - b_n)
>  \overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$$ (convergence in distribution) as
>   $n \to \infty$.

Since $X_i \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$, $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \beta$ and $\text{Var}(X_i) = \beta^2$. By the Central Limit Theorem,
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}T_n - \beta\right)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, \beta^2)\text{.}$$
Obviously $\dfrac{1}{\beta}\overset{p}{\to}\dfrac{1}{\beta}$, so by Slutsky's Theorem,
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\beta}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}T_n - \beta\right)\overset{d}{\to}\dfrac{1}{\beta}\mathcal{N}(0, \beta^2) \overset{d}{=}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)\text{.}$$
Thus, $a_n = \dfrac{1}{\beta\sqrt{n}}$ and $b_n = \sqrt{n}$.

The solution I have matches for $a_n$, but says $b_n = n\beta$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: $b_n=E[T_n]$, while $a_n=(\operatorname{Var}(T_n))^{-1/2}$; this ensures that $Z_n:=a_n(T_n-b_n)$ has mean zero and variance $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just did the   algebra wrong. Note that
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\beta}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}T_n - \beta\right)=\frac{T_n-n\beta}{\beta\sqrt{n}}=a_n(T_n-b_n)
$$
implies that
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{\beta\sqrt{n}}
\quad\text{and }\quad 
a_nb_n=\sqrt{n},
$$
which gives $b_n=n\beta$.

Comment: I laughed. Thank you. I shouldn't be doing convergence proofs this late. :P Will mark your answer as soon as this site lets me.